# Java expressions

Tags: java, while-loop, expression, java-7

I am trying to understand this code in Java 7 environment,

```
int T = getIntVal();
while (T--> 0) {
 // do stuff here
}
```

T is not modified within the while loop. Can someone explain this code?

Comment: [Here's a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c) which should give you the answer (even though it's c++, the behavior is the same).

Comment: What do you think `T--` does?

Comment: it is a bad practice to use a variable name that starts with block letters. There is no such expression --> in java.  dont confuse betweenn -- and > .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

what confuses you is that there is no whitespace between the `T--` and the `>`, so you might think there's a `-->` operator.
looking like this:

```
while (T-- > 0) {

}
```

It makes more sense, in every loop you decrease T by one

Answer (score 2):

The -- (decrement) operator will subtract from T each time the loop is run (after the loop condition is run since it as after T).

The simplest way is to just try it out:

```
public class Tester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("-------STARTING TESTER-------");
      int T = 5;
      while (T-- > 0) {
         System.out.println(T);
      }
      System.out.println("-------ENDING TESTER-------");
   }

}
```

Output:

```
-------STARTING TESTER-------
4
3
2
1
0
-------ENDING TESTER-------
```

If the -- operator was before T, the output would look like this (since it subtracts before the loop condition is run):

```
-------STARTING TESTER-------
4
3
2
1
-------ENDING TESTER-------
```